# Matrizes em Python - Concatenar

Tags: python, matriz

Olá, tenho duas matrizes e gostaria de concatenar elas, ou seja, colocar em uma terceira matriz as matrizes A e B uma do lado da outra, no caso formar uma matriz 3x6, porém utilizando um loop (comando "for") para isso. Poderiam me ajudar? Obrigado.

```
matriz_a = [
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1]
]

print(matriz_a)


matriz_b = [
        [2, 2, 3],
        [3, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]
    ]

print(matriz_b)
```

Comment: "uma ao lado da outra" - seria mais claro se pudesse exemplificar como essa matriz resultante ficaria tendo em conta a matriz `A` e `B` da pergunta.

Comment: Editei explicando corretamente agora, obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função nativa `zip`:

```
def matrix_union(A, B):
    for a, b in zip(A, B):
        yield [*a, *b]
```

O retorno da função será um gerador em que cada linha será a junção das linhas da matriz A com a matriz B.

Por exemplo:

```
A = [
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1]
]

B = [
    [2, 2, 3],
    [3, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3]
]

print(list(matrix_union(A, B)))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/WordyDaringConnections) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/9ImnQI) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/9a1ac8ef523931113a2c8456486f5cd2)</sup>

Irá gerar:

```
[
    [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3], 
    [0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2], 
    [1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nem precisa usar um `for`. Pode fazer o seguinte:

```
matriz_a = [
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1]
]

matriz_b = [
        [2, 2, 3],
        [3, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]
    ]

matriz_c = [*matriz_a, *matriz_b]  
print(matriz_c)
# [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 2, 3], [3, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

O operador `*` *desempacota* cada uma de suas matrizes (listas).

Se quisesse ainda assim usar um `for` e nenhum outro metodo, poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
matriz_c = []

for matriz in (matriz_a, matriz_b):
    for elemento in matriz:
        matriz_c.append(elemento)        

print(matriz_c)
#  [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 2, 3], [3, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado desde já. Acontece que eu precisaria realmente usar o comando for, porém teria que se tornar uma matriz 3x6, onde realmente a e b ficaria uma ao lado da outra. Creio que não expliquei corretamente...